# Use of Pandas to slice and create Lists

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

After some research on csv / pandas / etc to manipulate a huge csv file I decide to use pandas to slice just the information I need.
Now I am able to get just what I need using a filter i.e. "Name"="Greg" where I just see rows when the column Name has Greg.
However I would like now to create a pyhton List with all information of a specific column (i.e. City). How could I do that?
Then I will work just with the List to sort, count, etc.

What I have:

```
import pandas as pd

all_data = pd.read_csv(
    'myfile.csv',           # file name
    sep=',',                    # column separator
    quotechar='"',              # quoting character
    encoding='utf-16',
    na_values=0,                # fill missing values with 0
    usecols=[0,1,3],          # columns to use
    decimal='.')                # symbol for decimals



slice1 = all_data[all_data['Name'] == 'Greg']
print (slice1)
```

Example of print (slice1):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) with [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
#output is Series - column City
slice1 = all_data.ix[all_data['Name'] == 'Greg', 'City']

#generate list from Series
L = all_data.ix[all_data['Name'] == 'Greg', 'City'].tolist()
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

all_data = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Greg','Greg','Greg','Adam'],
                         'Coutry':['US','UK','UK','UK'],
                         'City':['LA','LD','RE','LB']},
                         index=[221,564,800,500])

print (all_data)
    City Coutry  Name
221   LA     US  Greg
564   LD     UK  Greg
800   RE     UK  Greg
500   LB     UK  Adam

slice1 = all_data.ix[all_data['Name'] == 'Greg', 'City']
print (slice1)
221    LA
564    LD
800    RE
Name: City, dtype: object

L = all_data.ix[all_data['Name'] == 'Greg', 'City'].tolist()
print (L)
['LA', 'LD', 'RE']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great input! Looks like Pandas doesnt like the data format of my City Column since it gets an error saying: KeyError: 'City' . Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe some space before word `City` like `' City'` ? Check it by `print (all_data.columns.tolist())`

Comment: humm.. I get :  ['\ufeffCity', 'Name', 'Country']. Not sure whats this \ufeff :(

Comment: seems to be an encoding issue.. Any idea how to go around this? I changed the name of the header from City to something else but doesnt work anyway.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Add parameter  `encoding='utf-16'` to  `read_csv`.

Comment: Could you please check my code updated with the new parameter? It seems ritgh to me but now I get an error because of that new line.

Comment: What is error? If need check file and is not confidental, send me it by email (in my profile).

Comment: This one:     decimal='.')                # symbol for decimals : ValueError: Only length-1 decimal markers supported

Comment: Hmmm, if omit `encoding`, all works nice? Need only remove weird characters?

Comment: If all works nice, only need rename first column, use `all_data.rename(columns={all_data.columns[0]: "City"}, inplace=True)` after `read_csv` with omiting `encoding` .

Comment: Great.. That was the easy solution :) Works great now!! Thanks a lot!